# SSRS Expression for getting current week Sunday-Saturday

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am looking to make a report that gets the current week from sunday to saturday, i was thinking oh the headers of it having the date of the current week of running the report, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming what you are asking is how to filter your dataset to show only records within the same week as the current week?

if so then you can do something like this

```
=WEEK(today()) = WEEK(Fields!myDateField.Value)
```

This will return `True` if the week is in the same week as the current week.

For more info on the WEEK function see here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/aa337345(v=sql.100)